# Sistema de horas extras en django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema a la hora de generar el código para calcular cuánto hay que pagar a cada empleado por mes, las horas extras realizadas y los fines de semana trabajados, en un sistema de administración para una empresa.

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```py
class EmployeeExtra(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Employee')
    job = models.ForeignKey(jobs, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Job')
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date')
    extra_hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Extra Hours')
    price_extra_hour = models.ForeignKey(PriceExtraHours, default= True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Price Extra Hour')
    weekends = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Weekends')
    price_weekend = models.ForeignKey(PriceWeekends, default= True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Price Weekend')
```

¿Cómo podría integrar ese cálculo en esta vista?:

```py
class ExtraHoursListView(ListView):
    model = EmployeeExtra
    template_name = 'extra_hours.html'
    context_object_name = 'extra_hours'
    login_url = 'website:login'


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search_query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if search_query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(empoloyee__name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(job__name_job__icontains=search_query)
            )

        current_year = datetime.date.today().year
        queryset = queryset.filter(date__year=current_year)

        return queryset
```